# What does "yet" at the end of a sentence mean?

Tags: word-choice, tense, time

I booked a room on a website and want to make sure the room is non-smoking. Therefore I wrote an email to the hotel yesterday and they replied me today:

> Regarding your reservation, we change your room type from Smoking to Non-smoking yet.

This message sounds great at first but the "yet" at the end is kind of confusing me. Does that mean "not yet" so I have to keep waiting?

---

I confirmed with the hotel. They've changed my room to non-smoking **already**.
@snailplane, @Damkerng and @WendiKidd's replies are helpful. Too bad I can only choose one as answer.

Comment: You're sure it wasn't, "We **haven't changed** your room type...yet?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Yet* is typically used in questions and negative sentences. For example,

> *Is she here **yet**?*
>   *Have you met Professor Hawkins **yet**?*
>   *I haven't got my results **yet**.*

Also note that *yet* can also be used in conditionals,

> *I want to see if she had woken up **yet**.*

Other than that, the use of *yet* in affirmative sentences is rare, except for a formal style, where it should mean *still*, for example,

> *We have **yet** to hear from the bank.*

But interpreting the *yet* in *"... we change your room type from Smoking to Non-smoking yet,"* as ***still*** doesn't make sense. So, it should be either one of the guesses in the comments by snailplane and NickStauner.

> ... we change(d) your room type from Smoking to Non-smoking **already**.
>   ... we **haven't** change(d) your room type from Smoking to Non-smoking yet.

In my opinion, the first guess is more likely.

Answer (score 5):

The reply must've come from a Wisconsinite since the improper use of "yet" at the end of sentances is rampant in Wisconsin speak, drives me nuts...

Comment: I believe this non-standard use of *yet* can be found not only in Wisconsin, but throughout the upper Midwest, as well as in Pennsylvania.

Comment: @snailboat That's interesting -- a parallel to the use around here (Missouri) of *any more* in positive contexts.

Comment: I say it and I'm from New York...

Answer (score 2):

As commenters have mentioned, this is not good English and is quite confusing to read. The sentence as they wrote it doesn't actually mean anything sensical. They could have meant either of these two things:

> Regarding your reservation, we have changed your room type from Smoking to Non-smoking.

(Meaning: you did not have a non-smoking room, but now you do.)

> Regarding your reservation, we have not changed your room type from Smoking to Non-smoking yet.

(Meaning: we understand you want a non-smoking room, but right now you still have a smoking one; we haven't changed it yet.)

But that doesn't help you, because you still don't know if the room type was changed or not! I assume they did change it, because it would be odd to write back and tell someone you haven't done what they asked yet... And also your request was not for them to *change* the room status, but to as *what* the room status was. So a reasonable reply to "Is my room non-smoking?" would be either "Yes, it is." or "No, it wasn't; but we've changed it for you."

To be sure, I'd reply with something like this:

> To confirm, my room is now a non-smoking room?

Hopefully the reply should be more easy to understand; a simple "yes" would suffice!